# what does !modified! do

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to figure out what the following expression means in a bat file I am working with:

```
SET modified=!string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%REPLACETEXT%!
!modified! >> %outvar%
```

This is declared for execution right after a delimiting **if** statement for "_" and obtain arguments passed to the execution of a script then separate them as strings and write the strings in a file.
More specifically: what do the exclamations (!*!) do in this situation?
I've searched for like an hour but to no result. Can anyone give a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `!` marks are the delayed expansion notation for variables (see `SETLOCAL /?` for documentation on this). Essentially, the `!` marks tell the processor to evaluate the variable at the time the line is executed instead of when it is parsed, which is the behavior of `%`.

Take this simple example:

```
SET MyValue=This
IF "%MyValue%"=="This" (
     SET NewValue=That
     SET MyValue=%NewValue%
)
ECHO NewValue = %NewValue%
ECHO MyValue = %MyValue%

REM Outputs:
REM NewValue = That
REM MyValue =
```

`MyValue` does not have a value because when the `IF` statement was parsed, %NewValue% did not have a value assigned yet (because the `SET` line had not yet been processed).

Now consider this:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

SET MyValue=This
IF "%MyValue%"=="This" (
     SET NewValue=That
     SET MyValue=!NewValue!
)
ECHO NewValue = %NewValue%
ECHO MyValue = %MyValue%

REM Outputs:
REM NewValue = That
REM MyValue = That

ENDLOCAL
```

This works because the delayed expansion notation `!`, tells the processor to evaluate `!NewValue!` when the respective line is executed.

Additionally in your case, the `SET` line doing the replacement allows for variables to be used as the replacement parameters. Delayed expansion notation is much easier to work with instead of having to break it out into `CALL` statements.

Comment: Both answers explain perfectly whats going on. I appreciate your help guys!

Comment: @NiU - Not sure about bash, but if you wanted to you could actually break out the code within your `IF` statement in batch subroutines and alleviate the need for delayed expansion - in most cases. However, many times it is not worth it and in your case where variables are used as parameters in the replacement line, it is significantly easier to just use delayed expansion notation.

Answer (score 2):

The exclamation marks are used for [delayed variable expansions](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), and are used in the same way as `%`-signs are for variables. This is mainly used inside parenthesis. This is because of the way batch executes loops and if-statements. consider this code:

```
@echo off
set "i=0"
if %i% equ 0 (
set "i=1"
echo %i%
)
pause
```

When executed, this doesn't echo 1, like expected, but echoes 0. That is because `%i%` get's replaced with `0` before the statements inside the if are executed. However, if you use `!i!` and `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`, like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "i=0"
if %i% equ 0 (
set "i=1"
echo !i!
)
echo %i%
pause
```

It will correctly echo 1. Also note that `!` is only needed inside parenthesis, not outside of them.

Comment: I find this accusation interesting considering our answers were posted at the exact same time (take a look at your edit history timestamps). Regardless, the OP was helped which is all that matters; the "gaming" that goes on within this site is frustrating at times...

Comment: @JasonFaulkner I'm sorry, I misread the answered time of your answer. If you can edit your post (1 letter or something) I'll upvote it.

Comment: I'm not worried about the upvote, I just get irked when a downvote is cast on an answer (which is correct) without justification. No worries - water under the bridge.